# Wordpress - Custom image for header

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use an image from a wordpress post as a custom header background image. I currently have it set to use the featured image (which works, but I don't want to use the featured image)

html (header.php)

```
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
}
?>

<div class="jumbotron-int" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $large_image_url[0]; ?>');">
```

I want to target a different image in the post. whether it's the first one, or one I an tag in some way. As long as I can control with one gets used.

I have installed the ACF plugin, as mentioned by another, but I can't figure out how to use it to do what I want

EDIT:

I want each post to have a different header image put in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the Image field in ACF

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

When you add an image field in ACF, You will see like the following screenshot
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/acf-image-field-edit.jpg

In that screen, If you select the return value to Image URL and Field Name is set to "header-image" (without quotes) You should use the following code to get the image.

```
 <?php $large_image_url = get_field('header-image'); ?>
 <div class="jumbotron-int" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $large_image_url; ?>');">
```

Comment: does it need to be wordpress version 4.4? to work, I am running on xampp and always run into issues updating worpress manually. I don't see that screenshot though

Comment: follow up question, is that each 'post' will have a different heading image

Comment: Go to this link, http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/acf-image-field-edit.jpg

Comment: Yes you can setup different image for each post as you wish and You can use any version of WordPress

Comment: What is your current version of WP?

Comment: I am using 4.4 right now but I don't keep WP as up to date as often

Comment: Updating WP is your wish, as ACF works well with your current version of WP.

Comment: I just don't see the second part. Where I can edit the image. I go to Media - Add Media - but I get the generic media window

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: The second screenshot in your answer. I don't see that one. I get the genric insert media one where I don't get any of those fields

Comment: I think you have not created the field. When you install the ACF plugin, You will find a tab named "Custom Fields" on the wp-admin menu. Go to that and Click Add New

Clicking the “Add New” button will create a new Field Group. When editing a field group, you will see 3 areas of interest; Fields, Location and Options. 

Title, Fields, Location

For more details to add a field to the Post Edit Page, Please see the link below for documentation.
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-field-group/